# jQuery: Loading AJAX content into parent of 'this'

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-selectors

I've tried out numerous ways to target the parent element and/or the JS object itself when initiating a super simple Ajax call. I have 3 divs with the same class, nothing more. When I click one, I try to get a .html(responseHere) to that DIV to simply change the content in it, but I can't find a way to select it without giving it an ID etc.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.box').click(function(){

    $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
        $(this).html(data);
    }, 'json');



  });   
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$var = 'This is some new content!';

echo json_encode($var);

?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    Click me to change my content
</div>
```

EDIT: When I alert() out the value of $(this) I only get [object Object]

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep a reference to the clicked element. Inside the Ajax callback, `this` refers to the `window` object:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var self = this;
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
        $(self).html(data);
    }, 'json');
});
```

<s>Also, `json_encode` will not work, you have to pass an array or object, but not a string. Either create proper JSON:</s>

```
$var = array('This is some new content!');

echo json_encode($var);
```

*It seems, a simple string is indeed valid JSON*.

There is no reason to call `json_encode` here. You can just return text:

```
echo $var;
```

(which implies that you also have to change the data type from `json` to `text` in the Ajax call)

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't give results. How can 'this' refer to the window object when 'this' is the selected DIV object?

Comment: @Melanie: Do you mean it does not change the output? Have you also changed the PHP? If not it won't work. Inside the callback, `this` **does not** refer to the clicked element.

Comment: Thanks for the englightenment. Though, using JSON_ENCODE -does- work.

Comment: @Melanie: Yep, you are right. Somehow I had in mind that there must be an object or array at the top level of a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, inside an Ajax call, `this` is the xhr object, not `.box` anymore.

Store `$box = $(this);` and later do `$box.html(data);`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Already tried a similar combination but without results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.close-btn').on('click touch',function () {
    // store this to a variable for later use
    var cc = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url:'del.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:this.id},
        dataType:'html',
        timeout:1000,
        error:function () {
            console.log('close failed');
        },
        success:function () {
            console.log(cc);
            cc.remove();
        }
    });
})
```

Hi, look at my code, it's what you need, store this to a variable (cc), and in ajax success we put the variable (cc) to it, finally you will get the answer.

Comment: Or if using ES6 features, simply using an arrow function.